# How do I comply with MIT or Apache licenses while making clear that these licenses only apply to the libraries?

Tags: licensing, mit, apache-2.0

I am making a closed source app for my employer. This app uses libraries under MIT and Apache licenses. How do I comply with these licenses in such a way that it is absolutely clear that these licenses only apply to the libraries and not the closed source app?

Comment: Portions are (c) yy xxx and are available under the terms of the apache license.

Comment: some people add a "notices" tab or document saying "the following libraries are included" then listing their names and copyright notices - I'm afraid I don't have time to dig up an example right now, try look at Google Chrome?

Comment: Is this a Rust application by chance? I have an easy solution in that case.

Answer (score 3):

If you are fine with disclosing which libraries you use, you can write alongside your own licensing information something along the lines of

> This app uses library A, which is made available under the MIT license, and library B, which is made available under the Apache 2.0 license. See below for the license texts.
>
> <MIT license text>
>
> &lt:Apache 2.0 license text>

If you don't want to disclose the names of the libraries, it would have to be something like

> This app contains software under either the MIT or Apache 2.0 license.